# 404 on template

Tags: templating

I have a section called 'news' (url: /news) and have setup in my templates folder /news/index.html which I could access previously.
I then created a route: news/* to go to another template and then deleted it. I can now no longer access /news and it gives the 404 error page.
I have duplicated the news template and renamed it to newsblah and when I go to the url /newsblah I can view the page.

I have cleared the cache on the settings page. Any ideas as to why this may be? very puzzling...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Route?

Comment: @BrandonKelly I worked it out - I had a section called news which was interfering with the routing

Comment: Great! Can you post an answer below explaining what the issues was, to help the next guy?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was I had a section called news which was referencing a template that didn't exist. Craft saw that for the /news url it should call the template defined in the section, but as it didn't exist it was displaying the 'page not found' page.